Work done on an object that is stationary
The definition of work is the energy transferred to an object via the application of force along a displacement. When referencing the work formula, $W=F\Delta D \cos{\theta}$, it seems that when we have a displacement of 0, there should be no work done. However, is it still possible for work to be done on an object, say by rubbing against it with your hand, since the temperature of the surfaces would increase.

Can work be done on an object even if the object remains stationary (at rest)?
If there is work done, what type(s) of energy are transferred?
Would it still be considered work if the object does not move?


It is possible to define mechanical systems where the center of mass remains stationary and yet work is done on the system, i.e. two blocks of equal mass moving away from each under equal force. If one takes as the system the block and rubbing hand, the work done by frictional forces is given by $W=\Delta E$, where $\Delta E$ is the thermal energy of the temperature increase, c.f. Sherwood, Bruce. Pseudowork and Real Work, American Journal of Physics, 1982. You can get the article off Sherwood's website on the web, e.g. Google his name.


However, is it still possible for work to be done on an object, say by rubbing against it with your hand, since the temperature of the surfaces would increase.

The trouble here is that you are trying to model a physical object as both a point mass and an extended body. The work equation you are using applies for a point mass or for the center-of-mass of an extended body, but does not properly account for other types of energy transfer.


Can work be done on an object even if the object remains stationary (at rest)?


No. The center-of-mass work (and your expression for the work) will be zero since the displacement is zero.
However, it may be helpful to note that this work depends on the frame of reference. Work is not frame independent.


If there is work done, what type(s) of energy are transferred?


Work is not done, according to your formula.


Would it still be considered work if the object does not move?


It can still be considered work, but the value of the work will be equal to zero.

"We call energy transferred in this way "heat" not "work."" I don't agree: heat is a flow of energy across a temperature gradient, but the transformation of energy to thermal energy during the process of rubbing two objects together can occur for two surfaces at the same $T$.  Energy transformation due to (macroscopic) friction unfortunately sits in this weird place where we can't quite call it work, but it's definitely not heat. Mesoscopic models of friction can explain the energy transformation in terms of work. E.g.

@march I updated the answer.

It looks like you’ve already selected a best answer—it’s unfortunate that the answers at the time* seem to have convinced you out of thinking that work is done during frictional sliding (work being a generalized force acting over a generalized displacement) and convinced you instead that friction constitutes one object heating another (heating being energy transfer driven by a temperature difference).
Friction does work. Since no object is perfectly smooth, with infinite stiffness, deformation of surface asperities stores strain energy, constituting mechanical work done by one object on another. Dissipative processes convert this strain energy into thermal energy.
Friction is not a matter of one object heating another. Friction can raise the temperature of two bodies in sliding contact even if they are identical and at the same temperature. Here, symmetry precludes us from assigning a heating direction. But each body does work on the other, with the net work depending on the observation frame.
*Since updated.

"Friction can raise the temperature of two bodies in sliding contact even if they are identical and at the same temperature.  Here, symmetry precludes us from assigning a heating direction." Initially they are at the same temperature. My argument is that the friction becomes thermal energy at the interface causing a temperature rise there. This increased temperature at the boundaries of the objects relative to the interiors provides the temperature gradient that creates a flow of energy by heat transfer to the interior of the bodies...

... This heat flow raises the temperatures of the two bodies equally in any reference frame and the energy of the input work is divided roughly 50/50 between the two bodies. If we look at the energy transfer in terms of work done by one body on the other, it appears like work is being done by body A on body B in the ref frame of B ,causing an energy transfer from A to B, while in the ref frame of A, it looks like energy is being transferred from B to A. These two viewpoints are contradictory.

(1) No one disputes that a hotter surface tends to heat the interior on any one side of the interface. The question is about the nature of the energy transfer across the interface.

(2) Energy is frame dependent, so there’s no contradiction; we expect to have to redo energy calculations when switching from one frame to another.


However, is it still possible for work to be done on an object, say by
rubbing against it with your hand

Your hand is moving relative to the object, even if it keeps returning to the same location so that displacement can appear to be zero on a longer time scale, but instant by instant, at the infinitesimal level, the hand has an instantaneous relative velocity.
If in a given time interval, your hand is moving with velocity (v) relative to the object, in the reference frame of the object, the work done by your hand in that short time interval ($\Delta t$) is
$$F \ v \Delta t = F \ \Delta d$$
where $F$ is the dynamic friction force equal to $F_n \ \mu$ where $f_n$ is the normal force of the hand applying pressure to the object and $\mu$ is the coefficient of dynamic friction. This work done by the hand does not become work done on the object because the object does not move in this reference frame (by the strict definition of work). Instead this energy due to work by the motion of the hand becomes thermal energy at the stationary interface between the hand and the object. This thermal energy disperses in various directions and raises the temperature of both the sander drum and the block by conduction and also disperses into the surrounding air by conduction, convection and radiation. A small amount of this energy is also dispersed as sound waves.
Let's consider the more subtle case of a rotary drum sander that is held against a stationary block of wood. (The motor of the sander is also stationary, but the surface of the drum is rotating.) In the reference frame of the block, the surface of the drum is following a circular path and we consider the length (d) of the circular path as the distance in the work equation, so there is work done by the sander but again this does not translate to work done on the block, but instead becomes thermal energy.
In the reference frame of the surface of the sander drum, the block is following a circular path around the drum and the block is doing work and again this becomes thermal energy at the interface that is conducted to both the the drum and the block. In this sense, the transfer of energy from the drum to block is by heat transfer.

Would it still be considered work if the object does not move?

No, because work is defined as energy in the form of a force moving a distance. There are other forms of energy, but they are not called work if there is no displacement of a force.

Instead of the term "heat", I think it's better to use the term thermal energy or internal energy.  Heat as a term should be reserved to describe a process by which energy is transferred via and across a temperature gradient (or to describe the amount of energy thereby transferred) so that "heat" and "work" are on equal footing as processes by which energy is transferred. The wording here can give the misleading notion that the increase in temperature of the surfaces of two rubbing objects is due to heat, but it's not. (See my comment on the other answer.)

@march Accept your comments on the semantics. I will adjust the terminology in my answer accordingly.

@march I have updated my answer, because I think I was double counting the energy budget. Does it seem better now?


When referencing the work formula, W=FΔDcosθ
, it seems that when we have a displacement of 0, there should be no work done. However, is it still possible for work to be done on an object, say by rubbing against it with your hand, since the temperature of the surfaces would increase.

When you walk around the circumference of a circle, eventually you return to your original position. While your change in position is zero, a distance $d_C$ of one circumference has been traveled and the Work done is
$$W = Fd_C$$
A simple rubbing motion is the same.
For a simple linear 1D problem:
$$W = Fd$$
Let's model a simple rubbing action as two steps:

Rub a distance d in one direction
Rub a distance d in the opposite direction.

This means no change of position after a rub cycle. The work for the rub cycle is:
$$ W = F(x_2 - x_1) + (-F)(x_1 - x_2)$$
$$W = 2F(x_2 - x_1) = 2Fd$$
Just because $\Delta Position = 0$ does not mean that the distance traversed is 0.
